# React redux modal, trigger single action on confirmation modal

Tags: reactjs

I have a redux modal and what I am trying to do is: Dispatch an event that will show a modal, and on click confirmation button inside that modal, trigger another action that will delete that record. As per my understanding, this is a two-action process, but what I am curious is that if there is a way I can turn this into a one-action process.

Currently inside my component

```
class Details extends Component { 
  deleteRecord() {
     this.props.deleteRecord();
  }
}
```

And my action

```
export const showConfirmationModal = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
    modalType: 'CONFIRMATION_MODAL',
    component:  ConfirmationModal,
    modalProps: {
      name: 'Record Name',
      id
    }
  };
};

export const deleteRecord = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'DISPATCH_DELETE_RECORD',
    id
  };
};
```

And then inside my saga on DISPATCH_DELETE_RECORD action

```
function* documentRecordFlow(action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action;
    yield call(agent.records.delete, id);
    yield put({ type: DELETE_RECORD_SUCCESS, id });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: DELETE_RECORD_ERROR, errors: [error] });
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way, the two actions can be converted into a single action. I tried dispatching an event from my on_confirmation event.

```
export const showConfirmationModal = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
    modalType: 'CONFIRMATION_MODAL',
    component:  ConfirmationModal,
    modalProps: {
      onConfirm: () => deleteRecord(id)
    }
  };
};
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I may definitely be doing something wrong in the latter approach, but I am sure the former is a redundant way of doing this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK So I have been able to resolve my situation by passing a callback function as props to my modal

```
export const showConfirmationModal = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
    modalType: 'CONFIRMATION_MODAL',
    component:  ConfirmationModal,
    modalProps: {
      onConfirm: () => deleteRecord(id)
    }
  };
};
```

And then inside my confirmation modal component, what I did is dispatch an event that takes in my callback function as payload

```
class ConfirmationModal extends Component {
   onConfirm() {
      this.props.confirmAction(this.props.callback);
   }
}

export default connect(...state, { 
  confirmAction: (callback) => ({ type: 'CONFIRM_TRIGGERED', callback }) 
})(ConfirmationModal);
```

My saga then with help of **put** effect does the magic part

```
function* modalWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('CONFIRM_TRIGGERED', ({ callback })* => {
    yield put(callback);
  });
}
```

Comment: mark it as right answer, If you were able to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Two actions cannot be specified as one if they dispatch a type that is not a part of sagas, you have a couple of options tho:

1. You can listen for the DELETE_RECORD_SUCCESS action in your reducer, and close the modal that way.
2. Add a closing dispatch after the DELETE_RECORD_SUCCESS

   `function* documentRecordFlow(action) {
     try {
       const { id } = action;
       yield call(agent.records.delete, id);
       yield put({ type: DELETE_RECORD_SUCCESS, id });
       yield put({ type: SHOW_MODAL, ...yourPayload });
     } catch (error) {
       yield put({ type: DELETE_RECORD_ERROR, errors: [error] });
     } finally {
       if (yield cancelled()) {
       }
     }
   }`
3. Is a good option if DELETE_RECORD_SUCCESS is a "commit" action, meaning everything has been updated and this is only as a indicator of success to prepare or clean the state. Close'ing the modal would fit in the context of the actions meaning.
4. Is a more readable approach and more commonly used.

Comment: thanks @dariusphp, I liked your approach too. I have mentioned in the answer below how I handled it to keep my modal independent of concerns of delete action.